# Import local Apple Mail.app messages (.emlx) into mutt

Tags: import, mutt, apple-mail

I am a mutt newbie, but am learning steadily, highly encouraged by its speed of searching and message display. I use mutt to read email from two Gmail IMAP accounts, and I cache the  headers on my disk in ~/.mutt/cache/hcache and message bodies in ~/.mutt/cache/bodies/.

I have a few years of mail I downloaded via Apple Mail.app that are stored in ~/Library/Mail/Mailboxes/.mbox/Messages/ where  is 2000 .. 2010. All these messages have .emlx extension. How do I transfer these messages to my mutt store so I can read and search them via mutt?

Answer (score 2):

From within mail.app, right-click on the folder you want to load in Mutt, and select "Archive Mailbox"  The archive is stored in mbox format, which mutt will open just fine.

to open the .mbox file in mutt, use 'c' to change-folder and browse to your .mbox file.  From there, tag all messages and save tagged with ';s'. Browse to your mutt store and save them there.  Mutt will prompt you to append the messages to the store.

Comment: This seems to work, in general. Can't it be scripted somehow? For example, for each user selected mbox, read, tag and save its contents in to a user specified folder in mutt?